# Wireless Adapter Hardware Not Found on PopOS 20.04

Tags: wifi, troubleshooting, pop-os

My wireless network was working just today. Then I took my laptop to another location to work which was a 5 minute walk, and then the WIFI adapter was completely not working. The computer did not go to standby properly when the lid shut, so the laptop felt like it overheated in the backpack. I'm worried that the heat broke the Wifi Adapter.

For the commands below:

- `<no output>` means that there was nothing returned when running the command.

Here is my information:

Computer: XMG Fusion 15 - https://bestware.com/en/xmg-fusion-15.html

OS info:

```
lsb_release -a
Distributor ID: Pop
Description:    Pop!_OS 20.04 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

kernel version:

```
uname -r
5.11.0-7620-generic
```

check the hardware startup and driver loading messages:

```
dmesg | grep iwlwifi
<no output>
```

check if the hardware is being detected by the kernel:

```
lspci | grep Network
<no output>
```

```
lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 8th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 07)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 07)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 630 (Mobile)
00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Thermal Controller (rev 10)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller (rev 10)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Shared SRAM (rev 10)
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 10)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH HECI Controller (rev 10)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake Mobile PCH SATA AHCI Controller (rev 10)
00:1b.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #17 (rev f0)
00:1b.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #21 (rev f0)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f0)
00:1d.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #14 (rev f0)
00:1e.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Serial IO UART Host Controller (rev 10)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM470 Chipset LPC/eSPI Controller (rev 10)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH cAVS (rev 10)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SMBus Controller (rev 10)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SPI Controller (rev 10)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU106M [GeForce RTX 2070 Mobile] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation TU106 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
01:00.2 USB controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU106 USB 3.1 Host Controller (rev a1)
01:00.3 Serial bus controller [0c80]: NVIDIA Corporation TU106 USB Type-C UCSI Controller (rev a1)
02:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Titan Ridge 2C 2018] (rev 06)
03:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Titan Ridge 2C 2018] (rev 06)
03:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Titan Ridge 2C 2018] (rev 06)
03:02.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Titan Ridge 2C 2018] (rev 06)
04:00.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 NHI [Titan Ridge 2C 2018] (rev 06)
06:00.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 USB Controller [Titan Ridge 2C 2018] (rev 06)
3b:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device a809
3d:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
```

check if driver module is loaded:

```
lsmod | grep iwlwifi
<no output>
```

Lists Wireless Devices:

```
rfkill list all
<no output>
```

Lists hardware:

```
sudo lshw –short | grep network
/0/100/1d.5/0        enp61s0         network        RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
/2                   virbr0-nic      network        Ethernet interface
/3                   veth4c078e5     network        Ethernet interface
/4                   veth5f7e22d     network        Ethernet interface
```

From what I can see here, it appears the wireless adapter is not even listed as hardware on the laptop, which indicates to me that it is broken.

Other solutions I could do is upgrade kernel to latest 5.13, or upgrade OS to 21.04. However, I don't think these will fix the root issue. Or I could call in my warranty and be without a laptop for a couple of weeks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The WiFi is now working. I have no idea why it decided to start working now. What I did before it started working was shut down the computer for a couple hours and run it on integrated graphics mode. Usually I set the computer to run on Hybrid graphics mode as the 2070 card is needed to run external monitors. The commands that didn't return anything before, now return the correct data. However this issue makes me worried that there might be a deeper problem. I think the thermals may have messed with the wireless chip and it needed time to cool off.